# what is the best algorithm for digraphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on a project in community detection. I have 2 csv files `nodes` and `edges` and I want to detect the optimal number of communities using implemenation of community detection algorithms. My graph is oriented, I have 5577 nodes and about 26000 edges.

My question is , as i already used gephi software but it wasn't that much helpfl for me , as he added too many nodes for me and the number of communities was not optimal , is there any implementation that can be used not only to detect communities but explore them as well for exemple to know the nodes that each community contains.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is too broad. How can you decide if a community algorithm works better than another? There is no known "best algorithm".

Comment: for example , we can say that for the oriented graphs a certain algorithm is better than the other because it supports for exemple the weight on the edges , i'm just saying , all i want is to find an implementation where i can load my csv file to detect the communities and explore them after

Comment: There's doubtlessly a lot of logic in what you say. However, I think you'll improve your chances of getting a helpful response if you make the question much much much much much much much more specific.

Comment: Mouad, could you post some sample data for the nodes and edges? And give examples of what makes a "good" community, and the criteria you are using for the 'optimal' number of communities. That will help the people here in responding.